# Find list elements that do not contain any of the characters ( . - \ / )

Tags: python

How I can find list elements which do not contain any of these characters `(` `.` `-` `\` `/` `)` without using `import re`?

I tried with this but it's not working:

```python
for wo2 in book_list:
    if "/" not in wo2 or "\"" not in wo2 or "-" not in wo2 or "." not in wo2:
        print (wo2)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Don't you just want `and`? Or maybe `all(char not in wo2 for char in bad_chars)` for a less repetitive implementation

Comment: i used this condition, but i did not the correct answer. However I want using `or`

Comment: Then `any` instead of `all`, but that's not what your question says.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of it not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. You need to [edit] the question and clarify the problem. "It's not working" is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I can see is that you have written `"\""` to check for the character `\`. This would actually be checking for the `"` character. Instead you should have written `"\\"` to check for a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is fine. You just have to replace `or` by `and` in your if-condition. See the code below.

```
book_list = ["book1", "book.2", "book/3", "book/\4", "book-5", "book(6", "book)7", "book(8)", "book10"]

for wo2 in book_list:
    if "/" not in wo2 and "\"" not in wo2 and "-" not in wo2 and "." not in wo2 and "(" not in wo2 and ")" not in wo2:
        print (wo2)
```

> **Output**

```
book1
book10
```

> **Update:** For simplicity, you can you `all()` in your condition:

```
book_list = ["book1", "book.2", "book/3", "book/\4", "book-5", "book(6", "book)7", "book(8)", "book10"]

for wo2 in book_list:
    if all(c not in wo2 for c in '/"-.()'):
        print (wo2)
```

> **Output**

```
book1
book10
```

Comment: Simpler: `if all(c not in wo2 for c in '/"-.()')`

Comment: Did you read @Nobozarb_'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683989/355230)?